# Gradle generates .apk old

Tags: gradle

Command in cmd

```
cd android 
gradlew installDebug
```

It generates a new .apk the problem is that it has an old version

Comment: An old version of what? Can you state what exactly you get and what you expected to get? As is, I have no clue what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

DO gradlew clean first that should totally work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please add some more comments around this answer, such as why it would work.  Also take a look at the help pages around answering for details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering